# Python socket server/client not looping

Tags: python, python-sockets

I'm working on a number guessing game handled over two clients connected via socket, but for some reason after the initial loop it stops working and doesn't send/receive anything. The code all executes fine the first time around, but no matter what I change, the second time around I either get an error at the line `guessNumber = int(s.recv(4096).decode()` in the server file - where it reports an error trying to change `''` into an int. This implies it's not receiving a value (in these instances, the Client program doesn't receive the `"What is your guess? "` string either).
The code below however just doesn't do anything after that initial loop, If you guess the number on that first loop then it works fine, your score is written to a file and they both end as they should.

But if you don't then it doesn't do anything either, so any help would be appreciated. It's running in Python 3.4.2 using the IDLE IDE.

Server:

```
import socket
import random

l = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

score = 0
guessNumber = 0

def within(value, goal, n):
    numDifference = abs(value - goal)
    if (numDifference <= n):
        return True
    else:
        return False

scoreFile = open('scores', 'a')
randomNumber = random.randrange(0, 11)

l.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4001)) 
l.listen(5) 
print("Waiting...")

while True:
    (s,ca)=l.accept()   
    print("Connection from", ca)

    while (not(within(guessNumber, randomNumber, 0))):
        s.sendall("What is your guess? ".encode())
        guessNumber = int(s.recv(4096).decode())
        score += 1

        print ("%d" % guessNumber)

        if (within(guessNumber, randomNumber, 0)):
            s.sendall(("You guessed correctly! \n Your score is %d" % score).encode())
            scoreFile.write("Player %s has a score of %d \n" % (ca, score))
            scoreFile.close()
            s.sendall("1".encode())
        elif (within(guessNumber, randomNumber, 3)):
            s.sendall("You are getting close!".encode())
            s.sendall("0".encode())
        else:
            s.sendall("You are way off".encode())
            s.sendall("0".encode())

    s.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket

gameOver = False
guessNumber = 0

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 4001))

while (gameOver != "1"):
    #Send guess
    guessNumber = input(s.recv(4096).decode()) 
    s.sendall(guessNumber.encode())

    #Recieve result
    print(s.recv(4096).decode())

    #Check whether game is over or not
    gameOver = s.recv(4096).decode()

print ("Game Over")
s.close()
```

Comment: I tried running them through Visual Studio 2013, it will now run for 2~3 iterations before, again, stopping working at the same point. I've determined that it is running the code to send the prompt from the server to the client, but then the client is not receiving it, and so is not sending a result, causing both Server and Client to reach a stalemate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the client was closing it's socket after the first iteration because it ended with a receive. I've added some send confirmations after each receive to tell the Server it was performed successfully, and now all works as intended!